Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Touchpad not detected
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 and am dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10. The problem is my touchpad isn't detected by the system and therefore it's not working. I tried switching to an older kernel and also adding some lines to the grub configuration, but nothing worked. The only time I got it to work was when I unplugged the battery inside of my laptop and started Ubuntu afterwards. Then it worked until the next restart.
Touchpad settings are not found in Settings app:

/etc/default/grub :

Results of xinput list :


Try to start with a X11Session, not with wayland. Does it work then?

Please never post pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Pictures can not be searched or scrolled and often have bits cropped.

Did it ever work in 24.04?

I didn't work when I started a X11Session either and yes it worked in 24.04 when i plugged my battery out and back in until i rebooted. Sorry about the pictures, it's the first question i wrote in a forum.

No, I meant that. did it work at all, before you unplugged your battery.

No before that it never worked.

See if this is your problem https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2064298 if it is subscribe to the bug to get latest info.
